# Grant a user access to directories shared by root (mod: 770)

Tags: linux, terminal, permissions, group-policy, user

I want to grant a user (username: eddie) access to all directories (with **mod 770**) shared by root (myself). I do it this way:

```
groups root
(here comes a list of groups in which root user is)

usermod -a -G group1 eddie
usermod -a -G group2 eddie
usermod -a -G group3 eddie
...
```

All the 'group1', 'group2', 'group3' are seen in the group list of root user.

However, after adding 'eddie' to all groups above (including group 'root'), he still can not write to directories shared by root user.

Did I do it wrongly?

Comment: Have you logout and relogin after add paul to the different groups?

Comment: hm, it's server, i dont want to reboot, anyway i'll try rebooting and see how

Comment: @Paul, you don't need to reboot a Linux server for perms to take effect.  (You don't even need to log off and log back in again, its immediate)

Comment: I'm unsure from your question what you are trying to do, hence I have not put this in as an answer, but might you be looking for usermod -a -G root paul   (To add Paul to the "root" group).

Comment: @davidgo, actually i have a project directory created by myself (root user), i want to share this folder to another guy (his name's eddie, amended the question). we both access thru' ssh.

Comment: @nitro2k01 answer is good - changing the owner of the directory to eddie would be a better move - security wise.  With the added information I do suspect my answer/comment is the command you were looking for - but, of-course, its not generally a good idea as it could give eddie access to more stuff then envisioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The owner of a file consists of two fields, one for the user and one for the group. If you do `ls -l` you can see the user as well as the group in the output. The group field in the file mode controls access for users in the group that owns a particular file.

It's irrelevant which groups `root` are in for your problem. Only the owner field for the file you want to give access to, and the other user's group memberships matter. If a file is owned by `root:somothergroup` and has mode `770`, `paul` can only access that file if `paul` is in `somothergroup`.

If you want to share specific files, I'd suggest creating a group that you add `eddie` to and, and change the ownership of the files to that group. (e.g. `chgrp -R somegroup somedirectory` to recursively change the ownership of all files in that directory.)

Also, somewhat unrelated, I'd strongly discourage you from always running as `root`. It's generally better to use a less privileged user account for daily tasks and using `sudo` or `su` to elevate your privileges.

Comment: thank you, creating a new group for sharing is a good solution :)